# Predicting cluster for new data point using k-means and Word2Vec

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, k-means, word2vec

I have been working on a project of clustering reviews (using k-means) in positive and negative clusters.(Dataset is of amazon alexa reviews).
The vectorization part was done in two ways separately:

1. Using `CountVectorizer()`
2. Using `Word2Vec`

Now, I was able to make clusters with both of these vectorization techniques but when predicting the cluster for a new data point (review in my case), I did it with the following code for the `CountVectorizer()`

**VECTORIZING THE DATA WITH `Countvectorizer()`**

```
vect = CountVectorizer(max_df = 0.95, min_df = 50)
count = vect.fit_transform(data_copy['reviews.text'])
count0 = count.todense()
count1 = count0.tolist()
count_df = pd.DataFrame(count1, columns = vect.get_feature_names())
```

**PREDICTING CLUSTER FOR NEW REVIEW**

```
print('Prediction')
X = vect.transform(['worst'])
predicted = model.predict(X)
print(predicted)
```

**VECTORIZING THE DATA USING `Word2Vec`**

```
w2v_model = Word2Vec(min_count=3,
                     window=4,
                     size=300,
                     sample=1e-5, 
                     alpha=0.03, 
                     min_alpha=0.0007, 
                     negative=20,
                     workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
w2v_model.build_vocab(sentences, progress_per=50000)
w2v_model.train(sentences, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=30, report_delay=1)

w2v_model.init_sims(replace=True)
word_vectors = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model").wv
```

Now my issue is, how can I predict a new data point after applying `Word2Vec` just like I did after applying `CountVectorizer()`.

=> How can I vectorize my new data point with the already built `Word2Vec` model? (Basically, what is the `Word2Vec` equivalent of `X = vect.transform(['worst'])`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `Word2Vec` code doesn't show how you vectorized the texts for the 1st application of the cluster algorithm. But: whatever you did then, you'd want to do for new datapoints. (It kind of needs to be the same words-to-word-vectors-to-text-vector process, whatever you did, as was used to create the clusters.)  Aside: is there any particular reason you've chosen peculiar non-standard values for `alpha` and `min_alpha`?)

Comment: Thank you for your response! It cleared my doubt and sorry about missing on the further code. Also, I am very new to Word2Vec and found this model implementation in a particular article that resonated the most with my project hence used it from there. Would you like to suggest any changes?

Comment: If it suggested those peculiar changes to defaults without explaining why, it's not a good article.

Comment: Oh thanks for letting me know about that, yes there was no explanation for the same. Also I realised I was only converting words to word vectors and not to text vectors hence the code is missing (I am very new to Word2Vec so and  had no clue that i'll have to convert word vectors to text vectors). Can you please throw some light on the same? It would be really helpful.

Comment: If you did not in fact get text-vectorization & clustering working with `Word2Vec`, you could correct your question to reflect what you actually tried & achieved. One crude way is to average all the word-vectors of a text together into a single summary vector. It's a reasonable quick-and-easy baseline on short texts for some broad tasks, but might not do well on real-world challanges.

Comment: Okay I understood what you are trying to convey. I'll try to implement it for sure!